# validation function shouldn't accept alpha characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a custom `directive` in my Angular app for form validation. I have a phone `input` which should only accept numeric values, for which I have created a `regExp':

```
var regExp = /^[0-9\s\w\+\-\(\)\']*$/;
```

Which I have then used within a condition within a function like so:

```
.directive('validatePhone', function(){

    var regExp = /^[0-9\s\w\+\-\(\)\']*$/;

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            function myValidation(value) {
                if (regExp.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validPhone', true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validPhone', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }        
    }
})
```

If I enter any special character such as `$%!` it pops up with an error in the front-end, so works. For some reason it is still accepting alpha values. I then extended the the condition to evaluate to true only if the `input` value does not contain alpha values, like so:

```
.directive('validatePhone', function(){

    var regExp = /^[0-9\s\w\+\-\(\)\']*$/;
    var regExc = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; //new reg exp

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            function myValidation(value) {
                if ((regExp.test(value)) && (!regExc.test(value))) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validPhone', true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('validPhone', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }        
    }
})
```

If I enter an alpha value at the beginning it flags the validation as false. But if I enter numeric then alpha values, it returns true `0178ar`, which isn't what I want.

***Question***

Why is my validation allowing alpha characters to be entered when I specified for it not to?

Comment: `\w` allows words in the RegExp.

Comment: Ahhhh. Simple mistake. Thank you. Leave it as an answer and I'll happily accept

Comment: @Kristaps it was the mistake Dez had highlighted. Thanks for your time anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`\w`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word) allows words (alphanumeric and underscore combinations) in the RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

Your original regular expression `/^[0-9\s\w\+\-\(\)\']*$/` includes `\w` which translates to "any word character" which includes, but is not limited to `[a-zA-Z]`.

Remove this from your regex and it should work as expected i.e.

```
var regex = /^[0-9\s\+\-\(\)\']*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

`[^a-zA-Z]+$`

Along with other answers the regex with ^ in the [] will exclude any characters from that set.  See https://regex101.com/#javascript

Or perhaps you'd want `^[^a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: Never head of https://regex101.com/#javascript . Thank you for the advice and tool